# Series equivalent to differences of inverse primes?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Would someone be kind enough to correct my error here?

$S=1+2+3+4+\cdots$

Now starting with the 1st prime number, regroup the sum:

$S=(1+3+5+7+\cdots) + (2+4+6+\cdots)$

$S=(1+3+5+7+\cdots) + 2(1+2+3+\cdots)$

$S=(1+3+5+7+\cdots) + 2S$

Now repeat the same procedure for every prime to acquire:

$S=1+2S+3S+5S+\cdots$

$1=\frac{1}{S}+2+3+5+\cdots$

$S=1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}-\cdots$

Does this logic make sense at all?

Comment: "Does this logic make sense at all?" No. You can not just equate sets with the sum of their elements.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please? Should I have written $S$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$ and called it a series?

Comment: That would be a first step. But even then you are talking in clouds since your series diverges.

Comment: Okay, so you're essentially saying they can't be the same because their partial sums are not equivalent?

Comment: You are writing (a) equalities between a set and a series of its elements, which does not make sense; and (b) series (infinite sums) that do not converge — that is, quantities which are not even defined.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean to use set notation, I am working with a series (mundane error). I have updated it now.

Comment: I do not understand the downvotes in this question. It is asked politely, the manipulation hints a way to fix divergence (considering the Riemann zeta function) and it leads to an important result, the Euler product, when put on the road. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart of some convergence problems and incorrect algebra in the very end, you have almost discovered a very rich and powerful identity, the [Euler product of the Riemann zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function). The main problem with your expression is that it diverges, but we can fix this problem by adding a parameter $s\gt 1$: $$1^{-s}+2^{-s}+3^{-s}+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-2^{-s}}\times\frac{1}{1-3^{-s}}\times\frac{1}{1-5^{-s}}\cdots,$$ the product running over the prime numbers.

This is more familiarly rewritten as $$\zeta(s)=\sum_{k\geq 1}k^{-s}=\prod_{p\,\text{prime}}\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}.$$ I'll add more on this in a better time, but this identity and the zeta function itself are central for analytic number theory.

Your comparison sounds quite beautiful, by the way: if the sum of all numbers is $S$, the sum of all primes is $1-\dfrac{1}{S}$. As written, this is mere playword; nevertheless, in the Euler product is hidden some deep number theory.

Comment: Thanks for actually listening to the idea, rather than focusing on syntactical errors and inexperience.

Answer (score 2):

"Does this logic make sense at all?" No. You can not just equate sets with the sum of their elements, nor can you divide by $\mathbb{N}$. But let us ignore that for a while and assume you had named the sum $S$.

The problem is that your sum $1+2+3+4+\cdots$ diverges and thus manipulations like reordering the terms, summing in a different order etc. are completely unjustified.

You can not just reorder the terms in divergent series, otherwise you end up with nonsense like the following:
$$1=1+(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+\cdots=(1+1)+(-1+1)+(-1+1)+\cdots=2$$

But ok, let us put that aside too. Then in your first step you claim

$$1+2+3+4+\cdots=(1+3+5+7+11+\cdots)+2\cdot (1+2+3+\cdots)$$

where in the first sum there are supposed to be all primes. Then where is the number $9$ for example? And $15$? You forgot all odd numbers which are not primes.

"Formally" the equality is of course correct, since both sides equal $\infty$.

Comment: 9 is taken care of because I said "repeat for all primes" which includes 3. So after 3 you have:
$S=(1+5+\cdots)+2S+3S$

Comment: @snd Aha so you mean $+3\cdot(1+2+3+\cdots)+5\cdot(1+\cdots)$ etc.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Does that at least make sense?

Comment: @snd No not at all. Sorry. But what *does* make sense is the following: instead of $1+2+3+\cdots$ consider  the (formal) power series $x+2x^2+3x^3+\cdots$ and then do you manipulations with that. If you plug in numbers $|x|<1$ then it even converges.

Comment: To be clear, the reason I can't factor is that my idea to rearrange is plagued from the outset? In other words, you're saying:
$1+2+3+4+\cdots\ne(1+3+5+\cdots)+(2+4+6+\cdots)$

Comment: @snd: No the equality is true, since both sides are equal to $\infty$. But this has nothing whatsoever to do with your manipulation.

Comment: If the equality is true, then what is the issue with factoring here to get:
$1+2+3+\cdots=(1+3+5+\cdots)+2(1+2+3+\cdots)$

Comment: @snd You are not saying *anything whatsoever*, all you are saying is that "Aha, if I sum up $1$, $2$, $3$, etc., I get infinity." and "Aha, if I sum up the other side, I get infinity as well". But does that really have to do anything with your "factoring"? No, since if you would have just taken $1+3+5+\cdots$ and left the rest out, you *still* would get $\infty$! In fact $1+2+3+\cdots=1+(1+1)+(1+1+1)+\cdots=1+1+1+1+\cdots=1+(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1)+\cdots=1+3+5+\cdots$.

Comment: @snd: 
Does that statement have any value? No. Is it "true"? Yes, both sides are simply $\infty$.

Comment: You are incorrect about the appearance $\infty$. The sum of the numbers $1+2+3+\cdots=-\frac{1}{12}$. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Comment: @snd: That is not correct. The Ramanujan sum (!) of the natural numbers is $-1/12$. The ordinary, plain and simple, old school, normal regular sum is simply $\infty$. Sorry. The Ramanujan sum gives a completely different interpretation to the notion of convergence of infinite series which does *not* allow arbitrary reordering. Otherwise you would get stuff like: $-\frac{1}{12}=1+2+3+\cdots=1+(1+1)+(1+1+1)+\cdots=1+1+(1+1)+(1+1)+\cdots=2\cdot (1+2+3+\cdots)=-\frac{2}{12}$

Comment: What is the essential difference between the "ordinary" sum and the Ramanujan sum?

Comment: The Ramanujan sum is a way to assign a value to infinite series by looking at the *partial sums*. Any partial sum can be written as an integral of the same function plus certain remainder terms using [Euler-Maclaurin summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula). One of these remainder terms is then defined to be the Ramanujan sum. This is a highly non-linear process in that applying it to the (componentwise) sum of series, one does **not** generally obtain the sum of the Ramanujan sums.

Comment: The ordinary sum is defined simply as the limit of the sequence of partial sums.

Comment: @snd: You are welcome.